TypeScript 5.5.4: tsc --extendedDiagnostics not showing JavaScript and TypeScript code lines
I have a problem with TypeScript 5.5.4. When running tsc --extendedDiagnostics, the output no longer shows the lines of JavaScript and TypeScript code. I have checked my tsconfig.json file and cannot find any configuration that might be causing this. Has anyone else experienced this issue?
When running tsc --extendedDiagnostics, I expect the report to return the following:
Lines of Definitions:       105992
Lines of TypeScript:         18361
Lines of JavaScript:         13154
Lines of JSON:               50974
Lines of Other:                  0

